# Open About Phone using Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I just want to open About Phone using intent to get the Bluetooth MAC address, I know how to open intent but I don't know the required action. Below are some of the common intents but I didn't find the one I need to open about the phone.
[Commen Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#OpenSettings)

Following is the code to open intent Action

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_....);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

oh it is simple

use `ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS` to open device info

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```